# How to use current MacOS $PATH in .app created by pyinstaller

Tags: python, macos, path, pyinstaller

I'm very new in coding so I apologize in advance.
I'm trying to create .app build of my python application.
The application sends adb commands in console on buttons click.
adb is in my MacOS PATH, so I call my functions like this:

```
    command = "adb devices -l"
    try:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
        )
    ...
```

and it work perfectly fine in my IDE.
However when I run created .app, it can't call adb.

I run this function

```
import os
console_output.insert(tk.END, f"Current PATH: {os.environ.get('PATH')}\n")
```

and in .app I see this output

```
Current PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

It seems like it uses some virtual environment.
I assume that every potential user of my app is having adb in path already, so how can I use current MacOS path?
Should I call adb differently?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how `PATH` (and other environment variables) work. Every process has its own environment and its own `PATH`, so there is no such thing as "my MacOS PATH".  What you probably have is shell initialization scripts that set `PATH` (and other things) *for your interactive shell processes* (which are inherited by processes started from those shell processes), but those have no effect outside of those shell processes and their children. Finding `adb` from somewhere else may be difficult.

Comment: thank you! so there's no way app can work as is on user's machine? do i have to force users to set their local adb path for my app?

Comment: Since `adb` is not standard on macOS, it might be best to include a copy inside your 'app bundle, and use that. Otherwise, your app should probably look in a few likely places, and if it doesn't find it ask the user.

Comment: thanks! that's what I did - added default adb path and gave the option to change it manually. seems like it does the job, gonna test on my colleagues